# WP7 beta testing: not available in my location

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace, beta-testing

I submitted a WP7 app for beta testing, I added some live ids and I got the confirmation email which has the zune://navigate/?appid=xxxx-xxx-xxxx-xxx-xxx link included. One of the live ids was the one I am using on my computer and WP7 phone.

When I tried to open that link, Zune tells me: CAN't OPEN, Sorry, the requested item isn't available in your location.

When submitting the app for beta testing there was no option to select the countries for availability, and my understanding is that the beta testing supports all countries.

FYI, my live id's location is UK, so is my computer's location, and I am logged in in Zune with that live id. When submitting the application, the xap packages has the attribute NeutralResourcesLanguage set to "en" - I understood that would make it available worldwide.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found in most cases the beta links only work when opened from a Windows 7 device, opening the link on a PC through Zune either gets a "app not available" or "app not available for your country".
There doesn't seem to be any setting in the marketplace to get around this so it may be by design.

No word yet on if this is fixed with the web marketplace but I doubt it since the Beta apps only give a Zune link

Answer (score 0):

Please find this workaround/bug report detailing this problem on the forums.create.msdn:
http://forums.create.msdn.com/forums/p/87910/531264.aspx

If the work around doesn't work raise a support issue with Wp7 Support:
http://windowsphone.create.msdn.com/support

Comment: I wrote to support, let's see what they say.