# Windows phone 7 app through Private Beta Test and worldwide distribution

Tags: windows-phone-7, marketplace

I have published an Windows phone 7 application to marketplace through Private Beta Test option.
But when the beta tester try to install it, get error message that it is not allowed because the application is not available to her country.

I do not find how to configure a worldwide distribution in Private Beta Test option.
Is this possible?

If not, what options I have to publish the app for testers with phones connected to different countries?

Comment: Hi, is the user in the same country as yourself? We've submitted a few beta tests and don't recall there being an option to turn on/off individual countries for beta release. All our beta tester though are from the UK were we are based.

Comment: My Live ID account is connected to US marketplace their accounts are Germans. So, should i change my country settings to Germany to manage to upload app which is accessabe from Germans phones ? How can be done this?

Comment: Hmmmmm, I'm unsure. Next time I do a beta release I'll keep your question in mind. Tell me, have you done another release since this one? Possibly gone over the options available to you a second time?

Comment: Haven't done any realease after that.

Comment: This answer has some hints that it matters how your testers install the app: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7819207/wp7-beta-testing-not-available-in-my-location/7833975#7833975 Maybe it also applies to your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few things to check before concluding that something is really wrong:

1. How long did you wait since receiving the "beta is now available" e-mail? It might take up to 24 hours before it is actually downloadable
2. Have you tried putting the zune link in a different format? ie. http://windowsphone.com/s?appid=xxxx